# Python Pandas Matrix Multiplication Multiple Operations in one

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to use the pandas matrix multiplication. I have four steps

1. Create 2500 new columns by dividing 2500 columns by 2500 columns
2. Use the result above and subtract 1 from all the columns
3. Use the result of point 2 and divide all 2500 columns by 1 column
4. Use the result of point 3 and add 1 column to all 2500

Is there a way to write this better, perhaps in a single line of code? It is currently quite slow and is CPU heavy.

The code snippet is below:

```
df_baseScenario[end_columns+ "fwd_rate"] =  df_baseScenario[start_columns].divide(df_baseScenario[end_columns].values,axis=0)
df_baseScenario[end_columns+ "fwd_rate"] =  df_baseScenario[end_columns+ "fwd_rate"].subtract(1)
df_baseScenario[end_columns+ "fwd_rate"] =  df_baseScenario[end_columns+ "fwd_rate"].multiply(1/df_baseScenario['Calc_Period'].values,axis=0)
df_baseScenario[end_columns+ "fwd_rate"] =  df_baseScenario[end_columns+ "fwd_rate"].add(df_baseScenario['Rate Index Spread'].values,axis=0)
```

Comment: Step #1 is a divide. I will correct the original question. This is all in one dataframe where I take columns 1 to 2500 and divide them by columns 2501 to 5000 to create a new set of columns 5001 to 7500. My data is 4000 rows and this takes approximately 10mins to complete.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying.  FWIW, I would just call that element-wise multiplication.  Matrix  multiplication generally means dot/inner/outer sort of multiplication.

Comment: And as far as speed, I doubt chaining will make that much of a speed difference.  If speed really matters, you probably want to go with numpy or numba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it a bit shorter and more readable, you can employ chaining as follows:

```
df = df_baseScenario
df["fwd_rate"] = df[start_cols] \
    .divide(df[end_cols].values, axis=0) \
    .subtract(1) \
    .multiply(1/df['Calc_Period'], axis=0) \
    .add(df['Rate Index Spread'], axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have two questions:
 - does python apply the code in the order specified?
 - if df[end_cols] and df[start_cols] are both 2500 columns by 4000 rows, is there any way to improve overall performance of the calculation?

Comment: To answer your first question: Yes, pandas applies chained methods in order. In regard to your second question: I'm not sure how to improve overall performance here. Perhaps you could try using numpy instead of pandas. However, I believe pandas employs numpy under the hood for such operations. Anyhow, clarification is needed here from others.

Answer (score 0):

I create code by text in question, no by sample code:

```
df_baseScenario = pd.DataFrame({'Calc_Period':[1,2,3],
                   'Rate Index Spread':[4,5,6],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3],
                   'G':[4,2,9],
                   'H':[5,7,8],
                   'I':[8,5,4]})

print (df_baseScenario)
start_columns = ['D','E','F']
end_columns = ['G','H','I']

df = df_baseScenario[start_columns].mul(df_baseScenario[end_columns].values)  \
                                    .sub(1) \
                                    .div(df_baseScenario['Calc_Period'], axis=0) \
                                    .add(df_baseScenario['Rate Index Spread'], axis=0)
#assign calumne names by end_columns
df.columns = end_columns
#add prefix
df = df.add_suffix('fwd_rate')
print (df)
   Gfwd_rate  Hfwd_rate  Ifwd_rate
0   7.000000  28.000000  59.000000
1   7.500000  15.000000  14.500000
2  20.666667  21.666667   9.666667
```

---

```
#concat columns to original
print (pd.concat([df_baseScenario, df], axis=1))
   Calc_Period  D  E  F  G  H  I  Rate Index Spread  Gfwd_rate  Hfwd_rate  \
0            1  1  5  7  4  5  8                  4   7.000000  28.000000   
1            2  3  3  4  2  7  5                  5   7.500000  15.000000   
2            3  5  6  3  9  8  4                  6  20.666667  21.666667   

   Ifwd_rate  
0  59.000000  
1  14.500000  
2   9.666667
```

Comment: Thank you. If I have a data frame that contains columns I don't want to include in my calculation, do I need to specify the column names, i.e.
    df['end_cols'].mul(df['start_cols']
Why don't I need to specify the .values or the axis=0?

Comment: You can omit omit `axis` parameter if need default values of parameter else need specify it.

Comment: In fact I have another question. My dataframe is 5000 columns by 4000 rows before I perform the above calculation. Do you have any suggestions for applying the calculation as it adds another 2500 columns.

Comment: I think you need `concat` in the end. See my answer.